# in c#, how can you disable a button after the 1st click, and enable it again after you click another button?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I cannot figure this out
i'm making a windows form application with visual basic in c#
i have a scan button and it scans everything in the folder and lists all of the files in the listbox

if you click it another time the list of files appear again 
how can you make it so you can only press the scan button once, and then you can press it again if you click the browse button?

the browse button is to select the folder you want to scan

thanks

Comment: "with visual basic in c#" that doesn't exactly make sense. Which language are you using to write code?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty trivial

```
 private void ScanButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      // do something
      (sender as Button).Enabled = false;
 }

 private void BrowseButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      ScanButton.Enabled = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit unclear if you're writing in C# or vb.net, but since the question is tagged as C#...

```
private void btnScan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnScan.Enabled = false;

    // other code here
}

private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    btnScan.Enabled = true;

    //other code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in my windows form application in C# and it works fine!

```
private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           int count = 0;
           count++; 
           //add your code here

           if (count == 1) {
                button3.Enabled = false;
                //only one click allowed
           }           
        }
```